# Continental GeoTIFF Failing to Warp

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I'm attempting to reproject/warp a series of raster images for continental Australia from Geographic GDA94 to Projected Geoscience Australia Lambert. However, aside from unexpectedly long processing times (up to 2.5 hours for a 7.5 GB GeoTIFF @ 160470P x 135683L), the GDAL Warp function stops writing out the data halfway through the image (see failed output below), and instead just fills the rest of the image with cells of value 0.

Does anyone have any experience warping large rasters and could explain what's going wrong?

```
Associated Error: "0...10...20...30...40..ERROR 1: Failed to acquire IOMutex in WarpRegion()."
```

GDAL Console Call:

`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4283 -t_srs EPSG:3112 -r near -multi -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 -co bigtiff=yes E:/ASTER_VNIR_SWIR_Reprojected/AlOH_Group_Content_Mosaic.tif E:/ASTER_VNIR_SWIR_Reprojected/Reprojected/AlOH_Group_Content_Mosaic_Reprojected_Bigtiff.tif`

[image: GDAL Warp Tool Parameters]

[image: Failed Warp Output]

Comment: Try warping to VRT then translating to new GTiff

Comment: It is not as heavy to write tiled TIFF `-co TILED=YES`. With your image the stripes are 160470 pixels wide. Error comes from mutex so running in single thread without `-multi` should prevent that if tiling does not make the process to go through.

Comment: @user30184 my mistake.

Comment: You need to gdalwarp it first to a vrt before using the translate